# Use a different value other than id

Tags: javascript, model, ember.js, ember-data

So, with ember it uses the id's a lot to identify models, it uses it in http request's as well like

`http://localhost/api/users/12`

Is there any way to use a different value as it's id? like a username for example?

so it ends up like this...

`http://localhost/api/users/john99`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i had to do this

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: "username"
});
```

After trying a lot of different ways, this is the only one that worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Route in Ember to tell what you wanna use something like:

```
App.UsersitemRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(model, params) {
    return { username: model.get('username') };
  }
});
```

in your UserModel you need to do something like:

```
App.Usersitem = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Comment: When does this serialize function get called? In my route I have the model function and the serialize function, only the model one is being called...

Comment: Let me also note, that the page isn't individual users page, it is a page that displays all of the users and when i make a change to a user it sends the id to the server where i want to use the username

Answer (score 0):

This method is called when transitionTo is called with a context in order to populate the URL.